# What persists through death?

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions, character-death

Some friends and I were having a discussion about the death of characters. What happens to effects when a character dies? I searched but haven't found anything really concrete except for attunement is broken upon death. Physical things that affect the body such as poisons would persist, but what about magical effects. What about a curse placed on a person, or the invisibility spell, or even insanity and other conditions?

This is with the idea of the different resurrections as well, as the more powerful versions restore and cure more.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/53553/15469).

Comment: Hi RacShade, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange. I believe, in agreement with Miniman, we already have a question & some answers covering this. If they don't handle the situation you're trying to resolve, can you tell us more about that situation to clarify why this is different? Beyond that, welcome to the site -- check out our [tour] to see how we work here, and when you reach 20 rep, you're welcome to join us in [chat]. You may also ask any questions you have about how the site itself works, or request assistance with using this site, on [meta].